# VBA and Excel, I am unsure how to run the method in my class on a certain sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have press alt + f11, gone into the code behind and written this:

```
Class style
    Public Sub IterateThroughData()
        Dim rowIndex As Integer
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim rowOffset As Integer
        rowOffset = 6
        colIndex = 1

        For rowIndex = rowOffset To 15
            Dim currentDate As Date
            Dim nextRowDate As Date
            currentDate = Cells(rowOffset, colIndex).Value
            nextRowDate = Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex).Value

            If currentDate <> nextRowDate Then
                RenderYearStyle(rowIndex,colIndex)
            End If

            currentDate = Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value
        Next rowIndex
    End Sub

    Private Sub RenderYearStyle(rowIndex As Integer, colIndex As Integer)
        With Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End Sub
End Class

Dim style As style
Set style = New style
style.IterateThroughData()
```

This should iterate through cells from row 6 column 1, to row 15 column 1.
It will get the value of the current cell in the iteration and compare it to the next rows date.
If they are not the same, then add a border to the bottom of that cell.

It's a simple test but I am having problems, when I run it, it says invalid outside procedure. Any ideas?

I am assuming that I need to

1. target a sheet on an excel file.
2. have some sort of proper place to add the global scope declaration of my style class.
3. correct any bugs in my code.

EDIT:::

**Class module**

```
Class style
    Public Sub IterateThroughData()
        Dim rowIndex As Integer
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim rowOffset As Integer
        rowOffset = 6
        colIndex = 1

        For rowIndex = rowOffset To 15
            Dim currentDate As Date
            Dim nextRowDate As Date
            currentDate = Cells(rowOffset, colIndex).Value
            nextRowDate = Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex).Value

            If currentDate <> nextRowDate Then
                RenderYearStyle(rowIndex,colIndex)
            End If

            currentDate = Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value
        Next rowIndex
    End Sub

    Private Sub RenderYearStyle(rowIndex As Integer, colIndex As Integer)
        With Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim MyStyles As style
    Set MyStyles = New style
End Sub
```

**Workbook open**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MyStyles.IterateThroughData()
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be allowed, but it is certainly confusing to use the same name (`style`) for a class and an object derived from that class.

Comment: Hah, I was reading how to define static class and got bored, really you didn't see the sweat blood and tears trying to get the static class to work :) but point taken :D

Comment: The way you've written your code, it will by default operate on whatever is the current `ActiveSheet`: you will find it easier to troubleshoot if you instead pass in a sheet object as a parameter to the class methods.

Comment: Nice, i'll give it a go! Can the running commands go in the global space like the first code I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom part of your code...

```
Dim style As style
Set style = New style
style.IterateThroughData()
```

...is not contained within a proper code block. You need to start the Macro from the [Excel Macro interface](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/run-a-macro-HP010014113.aspx).

Comment: Do I need to put my class into a class module? and then make a workbook_open sub? see code above - p.s it doesn't work. am I getting there? I really would like the code to run when the excel sheet opens (I have enabled all macros setting)

Comment: Yes - you need a separate class module per class.  Whether you need a workbook_open sub isn't clear from your question.

Comment: ah I see, so I have created a class and taken await my class declaration as I have set the name in the property inspector. Now I just have a class module with subs defined. now I just need to find the entry point where I can run some code to create an instance of my class and run the method defined in it!

Comment: Cheers guys, I got it